# GeoServer restores to vanilla installation and appears to have lost all data and customization

Tags: geoserver

We are running GeoServer 2.12.0 on Tomcat 8.0 on Debian 8.  At an unknown time, all our configurations and data layers have been lost.  GeoServer now appears as if it has just been installed, with an original default password and all demo layers in place.  What event could have caused this?  Is there any way I may recover our data?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have lost the `GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR` environment variable setting. To recover you need to set it to point to where ever your data directory is.

You should probably also update to a more recent version of GeoServer as the current version is 2.23.1

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred due to an anomaly with a particular installation I was working with.  It appears that the data drive had been moved to a different server and mounted back onto to Geoserver host server so the data folder could be used by multiple instances of Geoserver.  This server mounting connection had failed and hence Geoserver couldn't find the data folder.  In this instance it appears Geoserver then reverts to its internal data folder.